# Fantasy book help, read back in the early 1990's

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been searching the net in vain for a long time now and got nowhere, well until I found this site. Here is to hoping you can help me.

Back when I was in Secondary school (UK) in the early 1990's I borrowed from the school library a fantasy style book. Now sadly I cannot remember much about it other than it had your typical "assembled group" of young boy/hero, a warrior, a magician etc etc. 
All I can remember of the book was when they fight the main villain/antagonist at the end the fight is desperate and the hero seems to think that his magician friend has been killed yet notices his hand twitching. Then a Demi-God appears who was summoned by the magician who was actually carving runes with his hand on the floor of the battle area.

I may be remembering wrong but I think the magician had a twin brother, the boy had/met a girl companion with a possible romantic link developing. They travel to the enemies castle/cave/domain and attempt to battle him and as said the magician summons a demi-god to defeat the evil antagonist. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

That is all I can remember unfortunately so any help, assistance or nudges in the direction of will be most appreciated.

Comment: I may be remembering wrong but I think the magician had a twin brother, the boy had/met a girl companion with a possible romantic link developing. They travel to the enemies castle/cave/domain and attempt to battle him and as said they magician summons a demi-god to defeat the evil antagonist. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Confirmation of this dup is buried [down here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/98841/62201). Not the answer, but OP's second comment.

Answer (score 3):

Per Chris Green's comment in another answer, the book he was seeking was Douglas Hill's *Master of Fiends*, which is the sequel to his *Blade of the Poisoner*. The same series has been previously asked about and self-answered here at:

[Magic similar to psychic abilities, including hiding the group and starting fires](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39277/magic-similar-to-psychic-abilities-including-hiding-the-group-and-starting-fire)

and also perhaps in the following posts without accepted answers:

1) [Elemental novel where a boy discovers he has the power over fire and later over all elements](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41218/elemental-novel-where-a-boy-discovers-he-has-the-power-over-fire-and-later-over)

2) [Book ID: YA fantasy novel, possibly from the 80s, where main characters have special abilities](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67770/book-id-ya-fantasy-novel-possibly-from-the-80s-where-main-characters-have-spe)

3) [Book identification - quest to defeat impending magical death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75665/book-identification-quest-to-defeat-impending-magical-death)

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading some Dragonlance books by Weis and Hickman which included a magician called Raistlin and I'm sure there was a quest etc (which is most fantasy books I know) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raistlin_Majere#Publication_history I can't remember the specifics but it sounds similar I guess..... and if its not then you could read them as they are great books from what I remember.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I have not read the Dragonlance books, my younger brother has and assures me that although vaguely similar in some of the characters such as the two brothers that sadly is as far as they go. Before I found this site I checked out the story synopsis on Wikipedia of the Dragonlance books etc and they don't follow the same story. That said I won't rule them out just yet.

Comment: After a lot more research last night, mostly back into the Dragonlance books, I remembered something about either the enemy or the demigod being crystalline or something to do with crystals. Another search brought up a name of Annihilannic which rang a bell; further search on this brought up a book called Master of Fiends by Douglas Hill. So problem solved, I'm off to buy it now.

Comment: @ChrisGreen, if you found the book, you should post an answer, preferrably with a bit more detail about the book and how it fit your memories.